# How to hide a form element when a datetime widget is filled using #states

Tags: forms

The following code is working well to hide a button when a textfield is filled, but it is not working when a datetime widget is encoded:

```
$form['my_button'] = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  'submit' => [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t("Click on me"),
    '#submit' => ['submit_me']),
    '#states' => [
      'visible' => [
        ':input[data-drupal-selector=selector-of-my-text-field]' => [ 
          'filled' => FALSE,
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried `['!value' => '']` or `['!value' => '(placeholder value)']`? Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25295617/295112

Comment: Many thanks, it is working with `['value' => '']` (in my above code). If you add the answer, I can grant you the bounty!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"filled" won't work for date elements, but you can check if it is not empty with:

`['!value' => '']`